# при скачивании файла приписывается папка

Tags: php, download

Вот код который загружает файл пользователю с сервера из директории "/tmp" под именем "file.txt"

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
$file = $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    readfile($file);
}
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "<h1>Error 404: File Not Found: <br /><em>$file</em></h1>";
}
?>
```

При скачивание в разных браузерах выходит имя следующего характера, либо "tmp_file.txt", либо "tmp-file.txt"

Подскажите пожалуйста где кроется причина?

Что добавляет этот суффикс "tmp_","tmp-"?

И почему в разных браузерах разные имена на выходе получаются?

Comment: вы отдаете файл по абсолютному пути, со слешами, которые являются разделителями директорий, поэтому браузеру ничего не остается кроме как заменить их на удобные для браузера символы

Comment: @Etki а как сделать иначе? при помощи location? Добавил "location = \"tmp\"" не работает, это наверно не так делается))

Comment: отдавать в content-disposition filename без пути

Comment: Это то понятно) а как ему показать путь к файлу? сам он его не находит само собой)

Comment: в filename указывается исключительно имя файла, путь указывать нигде не нужно так как вы отдаёте файл функцией `readfile($file)`